# Finding edited system files

Tags: ubuntu, files, system-installation, backup

I am installing a new OS (old = Ubuntu 12.04; new = Ubuntu 16.06). I want to be able to back-up any system files I have edited on the old system but don't know all the ones I have updated. How would I find this out (if possible)?

Comment: How about [this way](http://serverfault.com/questions/90400/how-to-check-for-modified-config-files-on-a-debian-system)?

Comment: How long ago did you setup the Ubuntu 16.06? You could use find with the -mtime option to search for recently modified files, e.g. `find /etc -mtime -5 2> /dev/null` will find files modified in the past 5 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`debsums`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/debsums.1.html) can help you out quite a bit. The oft-quoted `debsums -ce` will list configuration files which have been changed, from the pool of tracked configuration files; so it's not a complete solution.

Instead, you should run `debsums -e`, and ignore any file which is marked "OK". Anything else — which includes files listed by `debsums` as "FAILED", *and files not listed by `debsums` at all*, has either been modified, either by a user or by a script, or is untracked and therefore needs manual inspection.